# Why is slime's "package" different from the inferior lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I think I don't have a clear understanding of how slime is running lisp within Emacs.

Say I have a file with the following entries :-

```
(defpackage "TEST"
  (:use "COMMON-LISP"))
(in-package "TEST")
*package*
```

Now I compile/run these three with either of say

```
C-c C-c
C-x C-e
```

and I get the output :-

```
#<PACKAGE "TEST">
```

However, if I now switch buffers to the inferior lisp buffer and type

```
*package*
```

it gives me the output as

```
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
```

What gives? Using the slime commands above clearly does something but it doesn't seem to be affecting the main REPL loop for the inferior-lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Global special variables**

Since global variables are using dynamic binding, one can rebind them:

```
CL-USER> *package*
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 117/256 internal, 0/4 external>
CL-USER> (defpackage "TEST"
           (:use "COMMON-LISP"))
#<The TEST package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>
CL-USER> (let ((*package* (find-package "TEST")))
           (intern "FOO"))
```

So you don't need to set a global variable, you can rebind them.

So something like SLIME can rebind them and execute the code for evaluation inside the rebound variable bindings:

```
(let ((*package* (find-package "FOO")))
  (eval (read-from-string some-string-with-code)))
```

**Thread local global special variables**

One can also create threads, such that they have their own 'thread local' global variables:

```
(sb-thread:make-thread (lambda (*package*)
                                    ...)
                       :arguments (list *package*))
```

Above thread function will have its own `*package*` variable binding.

**IDE and globals**

Usually one would want the IDE to use the globals in the current listener thread (each listener thread should have its own globals).

One also wants that evaluation from an editor Lisp code buffer uses the package from that buffer (typically the package defined on top or the package from the nearest `IN-PACKAGE` above in the code. The editor might also be able to set the package to use for the current Lisp code buffer.

Then an IDE will use something like above during evaluation: rebinding the `*package*` variable and/or use multiple threads with their own `*package*` variable binding in each thread.

**IDE and multiple inferior Lisps**

Typically there will be only one inferior Lisp, but it might be possible to have multiple listeners into it. Some IDEs might also support more than one inferior Lisp.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The current package in a file (or buffer actually) is determined by the first toplevel `in-package` form found when searching backwards from the compiled form at compilation time, e. g. when using `C-c C-c` to compile the toplevel form at point.  I hope you can imagine the looming confusion if if were otherwise.

The current package on the REPL is set by using `in-package` there.

You can conveniently set the current REPL package and current directory to those of the current buffer using `C-c C-~`.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. There is only one inferior-lisp running right? How can the same global variable in the same instance have two different values? As I understand it \*package\* is a global variable in the instance of inferior-lisp